# Scala case class arity limit and jvm 254 limit

Tags: java, scala

What is the new Scala case class arity limit.

In scala 2.11 the 22 limit was removed for case class.

What is the new limit?

Can it go beyond jvm limit of 254

Thanks

Comment: I'm just curious, is there any reason you would ever want to go beyond 254?

Comment: We are using Scala case class as schema generator. Many tables have more than 254 fields and that breaks in older Scala due to jvm limit. I am not sure how new 2.11 has been implemented so I want to know if that still is physical limit of 254 due to jvm method limit. Or it has been implemented in different way that it does not hits the jvm limit

Comment: "tables more than 254 fields" - have you not heard of normalisation?

Comment: It's already existing mainframe tables we cannot change.

Comment: you can always remodel part of your database schema which has very wide tables with views.

Answer (score 2):

There is no new limit. The point of the change was to remove that restriction (see [this](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7296)). Since it has been removed then it is theoretically limitless from the Scala side. If your table has more then 254 fields then I strongly recommend that you normalise your database design or even more drastically remodel your database schema because clearly something is wrong when you have 254 fields in one table.

Comment: Okay i checked creating case class more than 254 columns , the code does not compiles. It throws stackoverflow exception. So that is the limit.

Comment: This is very bad advice to give out in vacuum. The whole world of big data thrives in denormalisation and I've seen a few examples where it makes sense to have a very large amount of columns. Further more it has nothing to do with the question, which just asked about the technical limitation and did not ask for some ideology about data models.

Comment: Also sometimes you need to ingest sources and you have no control on limiting the columns from the sources, one suggestion is to use a map of column-name to data type to workaround the caseclass 254 limitation.

Comment: In some cases when working with legacy systems or external APIs, redesigning the schema isn't an option, no matter how wrong you think their schema is. Also, for some applications (such as data warehousing) tables may be denormalized for improved read performance. It does appear Scala 2.x has a limit of 254 supported fields, which is what OP was asking--discussion of schema normalization is not helpful for answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

The de facto limit is 254, due to the aforementioned JVM limitation, which will produce the error "Platform restriction: a parameter list's length cannot exceed 254." You may also encounter a StackOverflowError for a case class with 100+ fields, unless sufficient stack memory is provided during compilation.

As a workaround, you can nest case classes, each one having < 254 columns (similar to the workaround for the 22 limit). Or, you can use a normal class rather than a case class (just make sure that the class constructor has a parameter list < 254, or you may get the same error). If it's possible to redesign the data model to reduce the number of columns in one table, that's also a good option.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55492422/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-case-class-fields-in-scala), which goes into more detail.